# Best way to use EF Core DbContext between ASP.Net Core App and Worker Service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, .net-6.0

I'm trying to follow the DDD principles. I have put my EF Core DbContext in the Infrastructure layer.

I am sharing the domain and infrastructure layers with two application layers.
The first is an ASP.NET Core Web Api. This uses a scoped instance of the DbContext which is fine for dependancy injection.

The second is a background worker service which currently uses the `IDbContextFactory` to overcome the fact a worker service is a singleton and not scoped, thus meaning not being able to use the default DbContext DI.

On trying to merge these two DbContexts together I've realised my two repositories which are to be merged do not fit.

I have seen in setting up the DbContext you can define it's scope to `ServiceLifetime.Singleton` but I'm unsure on the risks in comparison to `IDbContextFactory`

What is the best way to handle this so the repositories can be merged and the DbContext can be treated the same way?

```cs
public class RepoOne
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public RepoOne(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext
    }

    public async Task<bool> Any(int id)
    {
        return await _myDbContext.MyTable.AnyAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class RepoTwo
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _factory;

    public RepoTwo(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory
    }

    public async Task<bool> Any(int id)
    {
        using(MyDbContext myDbContext = await _factory.CreateScopeAsync())
        {
            return await myDbContext.MyTable.AnyAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to DDD, neither application should care about the details of the Persistence (the Database). One way to do this is to Inject an `IInfra` into the Domain (`new Domain(IInfra)`) and IInfra will implement a "Save" method that'll be different depending on the needs of the application. They don't have to be the exact same object. If your Requirements require the exact same object you can still implement it this way but you'd have to design support for synchronizing the repos or maybe extract out a "ReadOnly" Repo to handle any mismatches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is more that because a worker service needs a singleton and asp.net core uses scoped, the way repositories currently use the context is different.

Comment: The point I was trying to get across is that you are having issues because you are trying to share the exact same object. You don't need to; share Interfaces not instances. Create a scoped Interface for asp.net and a singleton for the workers service; surround them with your Infra interface and Inject into the Domain. It's better if you keep them separate so that you can continue to optimize access based on the environment and you don't have dead-code sneaking in based on the environment.